# How to fix execvp() and stack smashing in my command interpreter

Tags: c

I have had the parsecmd, and runcmd functions provided to me from my professor, my task was to construct the main function to link these together. However, having the code as shown below results in some errors.
Firstly, execvp() doesn't seem to be working as it is returning. I am not familiar with the functionality of this function so I am unsure as to why this may be happening in my particular case. I have seen online that not correcting the last char of the command array '\n' does it for a lot of people but my parse should be handling that.
Second, I believe my execvp() line is causing some stack smashing. I have no idea how to correct this issue, or even if it's connected to the first.

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // For exit()
#include <string.h> // For strlen()
#include <limits.h> // For MAX_ARGS
#include <wait.h>   // For wait()
#include <errno.h> // For errno

#define MAX_ARGS 20 // For argv[]

void parsecmd(char *line, char **argv) {
    while(*line != '\0') {
        while(*line != ' ' || *line == '\t' || *line == '\n')  
            *line++ = '\0';
        *argv++ = line;
        while (*line != '\0' && *line != ' ' && *line != '\t' && *line != '\n') 
            *line++;        
    }
    *argv = '\0';
}


int runcmd(char *cmd) {
    char* argv[MAX_ARGS];
    pid_t child_pid;
    int child_status;

    parsecmd(cmd, argv);
    child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid == 0) {
        execvp(argv[0], argv);
        write(1, "UnkownCommand\n", 14);
        _exit(0);
    }
    else {
        pid_t tpid = wait(&child_status);
        return child_status;
    }
}


int main() {

    char input_cmd[50];
    int len;
    
    while(1) {
        //Print to screen
        write(1, "OS420>", 6);
        
        //Ask for input command
        read(0, input_cmd, 50);
        //scanf("%s", input_cmd);
        
        //Change last char from \n to \0
        len = sizeof(input_cmd);
        input_cmd[len] = '\0';

        //if input command is exit, terminate the program
        int cmp = strcmp(input_cmd, "exit");
        if (cmp == 0) {
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
            //parse input with parse function provided on canvas
            printf("%s", "Input Function -> ");
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                printf("%c", input_cmd[i]);
            runcmd(input_cmd);
        }
        
    }
}```

I get the output as follows with this code

OS420>/usr/bin/ls
Input Function -> /usr/bin/ls
UnkownCommand
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Aborted (core dumped)

Thanks in advance for the help.
````

Comment: *"I am not familiar with the functionality of this function"*. The read the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp).

Comment: `len = sizeof(input_cmd);` is wrong as that will always give 50 (size of the array) instead of the length of the input. Use the return value of `read` instead.

Comment: regarding: `*line++;`  In C, the precedence will result in the wrong order of operations.  Suggest: `(*line)++;`